# acr file not created when glossaries(-extra) is loaded by a preamble file located in a sub-folder

Tags: glossaries, makeindex, folders, directory, glossaries-extra

I think I may have run into a bug in the `glossaries-extra` (and hence, possibly `glossaries`) package.

I like to keep my preamble grouped in a thematic manner, eg. all standard packages (such as amsmath packages, etc.) go in one file `standard_preamble.tex` which is `input` into the file `preamble.tex` under the folder - `Preamble`. 2nd example - all packages belonging to `tikz` go in the file `tikz_stuff.tex` which is `input` into the file `preamble.tex`.  Finally, the `preamble.tex` itself is `include`d into the main document, `main.tex` .

Here is the directory structure to clarify up things

```
project_root
|-- 0_frontmatter
|   |-- abstract.tex
|   |-- acknowledgement.tex
|    -- dedication.tex
|
|-- Preamble
|   |-- preamble.tex
|   |-- standard_preamble.tex
|   |-- glossaries_preamble.tex
|   |-- tikz_stuff.tex
|-- latexmkrc
 -- main.tex
```

The `usepackage` invokation for `glossaries-extra` in `Preamble/glossaries_preamble.tex` does not work. In particular, if the `usepackage` line is not situated in `main.tex`, this does not produce a corresponding `main.acr` file for producing glossaries.

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

```
\include{Preamble/preamble} % <----- This is problematic for glossaries

% the below invocation works fine
% \usepackage[translate=babel,abbreviations,nomain,indexonlyfirst,acronym]{glossaries-extra} 

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{zoh}{ZOH}{Zero Order Hold}

\begin{document}
The \gls{zoh} circuit works well. We use \gls{zoh} for \dots blah \dots

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\end{document}
```

The file `Preamble/preamble.tex` contains just one line `\input{Preamble/glossaries_preamble.tex`.

The file  `glossaries_preamble.tex` simply contains  the same invocation as the commented-out line in `main.tex` i.e. `\usepackage[translate=babel,abbreviations,nomain,indexonlyfirst,acronym]{glossaries-extra}`

To summarize, `glossaries-extra` seems to be having problems with its loading from subfolders of the project. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do not use `\include` in the preamble. Replace it by `\input`.

Comment: @esdd aargh. That was indeed the problem. I am so sorry. What a silly mistake indeed. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the wrong usage of `include` in the preamble. When `include` is replaced with `input`, everything works as expected. Sorry for the noise.